# sintaxis digitalWrite( led, on ? HIGH : LOW );

Tags: arduino, sintaxis

soy nuevo en esto y estoy intentando aprender (frase muy comun en estos dias).

Quiriera que por favor me explicaran la siguiente sentencia

se que es para acmbiar el estado de la salida digital, pero ¿como funciona? , cual es su sintaxis?

De ante mano, muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis es

```
digitalWrite(pin, valor);
```

donde `pin` es el numero de pin y valor es HIGH o LOW.

La función `digitalWrite` se usa para cambiar el estado de un pin de salida entre los valores HIGH y LOW:

- HIGH pone el pin en `Vcc`, equivalente a 5V o 3.3V según el modelo de Arduino.
- LOW pone el pin en `Gnd`, que son 0V.

Previamente el pin debe haber sido configurado de salida usando `pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);`

En la instrucción

```
digitalWrite( led, on ? HIGH : LOW );
```

el pin `led` se pone en `HIGH` si la variable `on` es verdadera, o `LOW` si es falsa.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo mucha idea, pero en alguna ocasión he visto ese "on" como condición.

```
digitalWrite(LED, A > B ? HIGH : LOW);
```

Si A>B el pin LED se pone en HIGH y si no, pues en LOW